# Correcting a "Subquery returned more than 1 value error" when

Tags: sql-server

I have an idea what's wrong with this query, as it seems like SQL has disassociated my converted date (I have 3 fields i needed combined to make a date) from the Product table. My question is how do I fix it? I can't easily check if the current date is > greater than three separate columns, so I needed to combine them together into a single date.

```
select ProductID from ctbo.dbo.PRODUCT where (getdate() >
(Select
  Convert(DATE,CAST([expYear] AS VARCHAR(10))+'-'+
                    CAST([expMonth] AS VARCHAR(10))+'-'+
                    CAST([expDay] AS VARCHAR(10)))
                    from PRODUCT where expYear not like '0' and expDay not like '0' and expMonth not like '0') )
```

Comment: Your inner query (`Select Convert(DATE,CAST([expYear] AS VARCHA)..` selects more than one row. Check executing only the inner query...

Comment: Inner query alone works. It returns me a date.

Comment: Well a column of dates. I'm assuming that's my problem. I need my query to then compare current time to each row in the product table using that combined date as a temp column. I assume I'll have to declare that somehow?

Comment: Are you trying to get product records that have an `expYear+'-'+expMonth+'-'+expDay` greater than current datetime?  If you add more explanation for what you want we might do a better job helping :)

Answer (score 3):

Since your subquery returns multiple values you need to use either [ANY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175064.aspx) keyword (to make condition applied to any of the subquery result) or [ALL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178543.aspx) (to be applicable to all results) e.g.:

```
select ProductID from ctbo.dbo.PRODUCT where (getdate() >
ANY(Select
  Convert(DATE,CAST([expYear] AS VARCHAR(10))+'-'+
                    CAST([expMonth] AS VARCHAR(10))+'-'+
                    CAST([expDay] AS VARCHAR(10)))
                    from PRODUCT where expYear not like '0' and expDay not like '0' and expMonth not like '0') )
```